# Double.ToString() format different on IIS server than development

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this weird problem.
In controller:

```
Model ses = new Model();
ses.Latitudine = ses.Sesizare.Locatie.HotSpotLocatie.First().HotSpotLatD;
ses.Longitudine= ses.Sesizare.Locatie.HotSpotLocatie.First().HotSpotLatD;
```

In model:

```
public class Model
{
    public double Latitudine {get; set;}
    public double Longitudine {get; set;}
}
```

In View:

```
<h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> <a style="color:white" target='_blank' href='@("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + Model.Latitudine + "," + Model.Longitudine)'>Locatia:</a> </h4>
```

Now in Visual Studio debugging the view is rendered like:

```
<h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> <a style="color:white" target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=45.65933,25.561595">Locatia:</a> </h4>
```

**http://maps.google.com/maps?q=45.65933,25.561595**(Link usable)

Yet after publishing I get:

```
<h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> <a style="color:white" target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=45,65933,25,561595">Locatia:</a> </h4>
```

**http://maps.google.com/maps?q=45,65933,25,561595**(Link unusable)

Development and Production is on same machine.

In another controller I have:

```
 Latitude = t.LocatieGPS.Latitude.ToString();
```

and here the result uses DOT in both production and development.

This is Production WebConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    ....
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="GestiuneServiceWeb.Startup,GestiuneServiceWeb" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure they use same culture settings?

Comment: what do you mean by they?

Comment: Show your Web.Config

Comment: @AlinI By "they", he means the two different machines.

Comment: @JLRishe I have specified that webserver and visual studio is on same machine

Comment: Check this node '<globalization culture="???" />' in your webConfig.Debug and Webconfig.release files. If you get answer to your question do post please.

Comment: Are both Developer and Production using the same IIS? Is Development uses IIS Express?

Comment: Yes, VS is using IIS Express for debugging, while the Website is on IIS.

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by the culture of the machine. You probably don't want to change the culture for your entire application, so just specify how you want the decimals formatted.

The `InvariantCulture` uses a dot as decimal separator:

```
@("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + Model.Latitudine.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "," + Model.Longitudine.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Comment: I want to change the culture for the entire application. And I want it to be the same during development and production. The problem is that Decimal.ToString() renders **commas** only on this particular controller, in another controller it renders a **period**. In development it renders a **period** on both controllers...

Comment: Then you got to find out the differences between those controllers and views.

Answer (score 2):

This probably has to do with the culture you are using in IIS. To override this in your case, without changing the culture anywhere else, you could perhaps format the link as follows:

```
href='@("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + 
     Model.Latitudine.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "," + 
     Model.LongitudineToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))'
```

This will convert the number to a string, and output it with the settings for "InvariantCulture", which will use a dot instead of a comma.

Comment: Ok, but I want the culture to be the same. and use **dot** for decimal

Comment: "period" means the same as "dot" in this case, but I'll change it in my answer anyway, since I'm guessing more SO readers will be more familiar with the term "dot" ;). As for the change in culture, it will pertain only the the specific string you are outputting. Would that be a problem?

Comment: Yes. The problem appears only in this controller. I have another controller that returns JSON, and that controller's .ToString() method renders doubles using a dot or period, instead of a comma.